# Apply a predicate to a list of inputs Prolog

Tags: prolog, tau-prolog

What i'm trying to do is:

Given a list of characters to know which list best contradicts it, so image I put on the list `[kraken,scorpia,zulrah]` so it will check the type of attack of each and would see would be the most effective type of attack for each and with that, I would receive a list of 3 bosses.

```
% boss(Name, Type) Name = Name of boss, Type = Attack type
boss(kraken,magic).
boss(scorpia,melee).
boss(zulrah,ranged).
boss(cerberus,melee).
boss(abyssal_sire,melee).
boss(obor,melee).
boss(sarachnis,ranged).
boss(skotizo,melee).
boss(venenatis,magic).

superEffective(magic,melee). %magic is more effective against melee
superEffective(ranged,magic). %ranged is more effective against magic
superEffective(melee,ranged). %melee is more effective against ranged
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to input 3 bosses and you want the output to be the 3 best bosses that best contradicts all monsters at same time? Or you want the best contradictor of each one in the list? Can you give an example of the input predicate and the desired output?

Comment: you can place as many bosses as you want, just said one example. Yes. I want the best contradictor of each one in the list. Like this:
input: [kraken,scorpia,zulrah]
output: [skotizo,sarachnis,venenatis]

Comment: But you can have multiple possible outputs given a set of input. Can any answer be considered valid? Why could not the output be: `[scorpia, zulrah, kraken]`?

Comment: yes it can also be. I just said an example of input and output.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, create a predicate to verify the counter of a single Boss:

```
verify_con(Boss, ConBoss) :- boss(Boss,MainSkill), 
                             superEffective(MainSkill,ConSkill), 
                             boss(ConBoss,ConSkill), !.
```

Notice that this predicate will get always **the first best counter** to the input boss. If you want all the possible combinations, just delete the `, !` at the end.

**Second**, use recursion to iterate over the input list and build the output list. You can use [`append/3`](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/lists/append/3) to append the output array.

```
verify_con_list([],[]).
verify_con_list([H|T], LIST) :- verify_con(H, ConBoss), 
                                verify_con_list(T, L1), 
                                append([ConBoss],L1, LIST).
```

If necessary, you can define the `append/3` function at the top of your code like this:

```
append([], X, X).
append([H|T], X, [H|S]) :- append(T, X, S).
```

---

### Examples

Single output:

```
?- verify_con(kraken, A).

A = scorpia
```

List input:

```
?- verify_con_list([kraken, scorpia, zulrah], Con).

Con = [scorpia, zulrah, kraken]
```

### Full code:

```
append( [], X, X).                        
append( [X | Y], Z, [X | W]) :- append( Y, Z, W).  

% boss(Name, Type) Name = Name of boss, Type = Attack type
boss(kraken,magic).
boss(scorpia,melee).
boss(zulrah,ranged).
boss(cerberus,melee).
boss(abyssal_sire,melee).
boss(obor,melee).
boss(sarachnis,ranged).
boss(skotizo,melee).
boss(venenatis,magic).

superEffective(magic,melee). %magic is more effective against melee
superEffective(ranged,magic). %ranged is more effective against magic
superEffective(melee,ranged). %melee is more effective against ranged

verify_con(Boss, ConBoss) :- boss(Boss,MainSkill), 
                             superEffective(MainSkill,ConSkill), 
                             boss(ConBoss,ConSkill), !.

verify_con_list([],[]).
verify_con_list([H|T], LIST) :- verify_con(H, ConBoss), 
                                verify_con_list(T, L1), 
                                append([ConBoss],L1, LIST).



%verify_con(kraken, A).
%verify_con_list([kraken, scorpia, zulrah], Con).
```